# How to use RenderForm together with RawInput and SharpDX?

Tags: c#, raw-input

It's easy with slimdx. Just register the device and the event:

```
SharpDX.RawInput.Device.RegisterDevice(UsagePage.Generic, UsageId.GenericKeyboard, SharpDX.RawInput.DeviceFlags.None);
SharpDX.RawInput.Device.KeyboardInput += new System.EventHandler<KeyboardInputEventArgs>(Device_KeyboardInput);
```

But this won't work with SharpDX. Device_KeyboardInput isn't called when I use the suggested renderloop:

```
RenderLoop.Run(renderForm, () =>
{
}
```

It's work somehow (mouse works, but keyboard not really) when I add Application.DoEvents() to the loop. DoEvents() should not be used when I interpret this [slimdx tutorial](http://slimdx.org/tutorials/BasicWindow.php) right. The sharpdx RawInput works only with a normal window like it is used in the [sharpdx rawinput example](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/browse/Samples/RawInput/RawInputTrackApp/Program.cs).

How can I use RawInput with SharpDX with a RenderLoop?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug by SharpDX and it's fixed now: http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/detail?r=5b80d6dea7f8